# How can I delete a row by its SKU instead of its ID?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, angular-cli

I try to delete the row using the sku of the product. I'm using spring boot and angular. I got an error when I added the sku on my button like this one  `(click)="onDeleteProductBySku(deleteClick?.sku)"` it said that the `Property 'sku' does not exist on type '(product: Product) => void'.`. On my command prompt, I got this error. How can I solve this problem?

```
Error: product/product.component.html:50:109 - error TS2339: Property 'sku' does not exist on type '(product: Product) => void'.

50 <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm me-2" (click)="onDeleteProductBySku(deleteClick?.sku)">Delete</button>
                                                                                                                                  
product/product.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.
```

ProductsController.java --> This is working on the postman.

```
//Delete a product record using sku
//http://localhost:8080/products/deletebysku?sku=12345678

@DeleteMapping("/products/deletebysku")
@ResponseBody
private void deleteProductBySku(@RequestParam String sku){
    productsService.deleteProductBySku(sku);
}
```

product.component.ts

```
 public deleteProduct!: Product;

 public onDeleteProductBySku(sku: string): void {
    this.productServive.deleteProductBySku(sku).subscribe(
      (response: void) => {
        this.messageShow();
        console.log(response);
        this.getAllProduct();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage(error.message);
      }
    );
 }

 public deleteClick(product: Product) {
   this.deleteProduct = product;
   console.log("delete by sku");
 }
```

product.service.ts

```
public deleteProductBySku(sku: string): Observable<void> {
  return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/products/deletebysku?sku=${sku}`);
}
```

product.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm me-2" (click)="onDeleteProductBySku(deleteClick?.sku)">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `deleteClick` is a function of type void, which does not return nor does it contain `sku` property. Didn't you mean to call the delete function like this?

```html
<button 
  class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm me-2"
  (click)="onDeleteProductBySku(product?.sku)"
>
Delete
</button>

<!-- Or maybe?
(click)="onDeleteProductBySku(this.deleteProduct?.sku)"
-->
```

Comment: The argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more code. Is this function `deleteClick(product: Product)` ever called? How are both `deleteProduct` and `product` variables defined and initialized? As before, `sku` is not defined on the object you are passing to `onDeleteProductBySku` function.

Comment: I put the (click)="deleteClick(product)" function to my delete button, when the user clicks the button a modal will be pop-up then on the modal I add a button yes then I put this function (click)="onDeleteProductBySku(deleteProduct.sku)", It's working now.